# In D3, how can I bind two rectangles to the same selection using different data?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am working with Bill White's Virtual Scrolling class as a basis for my code. It can be seen [here.](http://bl.ocks.org/billdwhite/36d15bc6126e6f6365d0)

I have two sets of data - reference data that I have millions of rows of, and variant data that I only have 9 of. I want to display the variant data on the same row as the reference data when the variant data and the reference data appear at the same index.

I have a rowEnter function

```
        var rowEnter = function(rowSelection) {
        rowSelection.append("rect")
            .attr("rx", 3)
            .attr("ry", 3)
            .attr("width", "125")
            .attr("height", "30")
            .attr("fill-opacity", 0.25)
            .attr("stroke", "#999999")
            .attr("stroke-width", "2px");
        rowSelection.append("text")
            .attr("transform", "translate(10,20)");
    };
```

And a rowUpdate function

```
    var rowUpdate = function(rowSelection)
    {
        rowSelection.selectAll("rect")
            .append("rect")
            .attr("fill", "#df4440");
            rowSelection.select("text")
                .append("text")
                .text(d.id + d.label);
    }
```

And it's all called here

```
        var virtualScroller = d3.VirtualScroller()
        .rowHeight(30)
        .enter(rowEnter)
        .update(rowUpdate)
        .exit(rowExit)
        .svg(scrollSVG)
        .totalRows(5090493)
        .viewport(d3.select(".viewport"));
```

I want to add something like the following...

```
        var rowEnterVariant = function(variantData) {
        rowSelection.append("rect")
            .attr("rx", 6)
            .attr("ry", 6)
            .attr("width", "125")
            .attr("height", "24")
            .attr("fill-opacity", 0.25)
            .attr("stroke", "#999999")
            .attr("stroke-width", "2px");
        rowSelection.append("text")
            .attr("transform", "translate(10,20)");
    };
```

And...

```
        var variantUpdate = function(rowSelection, variantData)
    {
        rowSelection.selectAll("rect")
            .append("rect")
            .attr("fill", function(d) {
                if(d.id == variantData.items[i].position)
                {
                    var red = "#df4440";
                    return red;
                }
            });
            rowSelection.select("text")
                .append("text")
                .text(variantData.items[i].variation);
    }
```

Which would ideally add a rectangle next to the original reference rectangle, this time with my variant data inside of it, only being rendered when the variant data and the reference data coincide.

I cannot figure out how to implement this. I believe the solution has something to do with nested selection (I could select my reference and variant data together, and apply data binding to each of them individually), but I cannot figure out how.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes, it sounds like you want nested selections here. The idea is to merge your two data sources and for each item have an array that contains either one element (only reference) or two (reference + variant). Then you can do something like `var rows = svg.selectAll("g.row").data(data)... rows.selectAll("rect").data(function(d) { return d; }).enter().append("rect")....`

Comment: Okay, great. I will work on merging my data sources, now that you mention that it seems like that is what is giving me trouble.

Comment: What do you mean by "g.row" in the above example?

Comment: That's a selector for `g` elements with class `row`. You don't have to use exactly that.

Comment: Thanks. I will work on a solution to merging my data.